# Mongodb doesn't connect to localhost when using node.js+ mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making an app on Node.js and trying to connect to MongoDB via mongoose. When I run it, in cmd it shows "connected to MongoDB database", but this is what it shows when I run mongo. It doesn't say connected
[Mongo connection status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk04X.png)

Also, when I try to connect MongoDB compass to localhost:27017, it shows the error " read ECONNRESET".
So clearly, for some reason, my MongoDB is not connected to the localhost. Can someone help me out? here is my mongoose connection code in app.js.
[App.js Mongoose connection code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwbL7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your mongod.conf file to see the port the server is set to run on.If on linux and running as a service use systemctl status mongod to ensure the process is running. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run the command- " mongod " in another window and check.

Comment: Please add your suggestions in the comment section instead of posting it as an answer

Comment: Ok, I will take care. I am a new user and need some practice with the rules.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not connecting, simply go in that path:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin
```

and click shift + right, open window PowerShell or any other command prompt, and then type `mongod` like that:

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin> mongod
```

and connect to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just followed these simple steps:

1. Type here to search -- Services -- Click on that
2. Find -- MongoDB Server(MongoDB) -- Click on that
3. On the left site of window You will see -- Start-- link. Click on that,
   and your problem is solved.